# Hot Topics in Labor-Macro

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, academic-graduate

I'm interested in currently hot research topics within Labor Macro. I'm only aware of the debate on the recent [shift in the US Beveridge curve](http://web.stanford.edu/~rehall/Labor%20Market%20Current%20Slump%202010.pdf), and, of course, the olden but golden Shimer puzzle.

What else are current debates within Labor Macro?

Comment: According to the "Help Center" this kind of question is not really appropriate here http://economics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I think it's ok. It's useful information for researchers and this is an academic orientated site.